# How to get the project Name and project Number through audit logs or through API's in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to retrieve the project details such as `projectName` and `projectNumber` in [bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#projects), but anywhere I can see only the `projectId` but not other details. I have explored the [audit logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) in my project when I ran a query and seen all the types of audit logs whether anywhere I can be able to find those details, but I was able to see the `projectId` only. I also explored the API's like is there any API serving my purpose, I have found one [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list) which gives the list of projects but there also they are not providing the `projectName` and `projectNumber` details. So is there any other way I can get those details, please let me know.

EDIT: Looking for the JAVA API client

Answer (score 0):

From bigquery resources you can use its client library (which makes use of the API) to get that information.

**UPDATED 12/07/2021**: JAVA API

Unfortunately this was take out of JAVA API BIGQUERY Client and there is no news if it will make a return. So, you wont be able to get such information from BigQuery latest client. You can see one discussion about it [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3397).

Regardless of that you will be able to get that info using `resource manager`. ( although you will need to have the information from the hierarchy above or at least the project name )

libraries used

```
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.Project;
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.ProjectName;
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.ProjectsClient;
```

code

```
try (ProjectsClient projectsClient = ProjectsClient.create()) { 
     ProjectName name = ProjectName.of("[PROJECT]");
     Project prjct = projectsClient.getProject(name); 
     System.out.println(prjct.getProjectId());
     System.out.println(prjct.getName()); # returns `projects/415104041262`
}
```

To setup `DOM` and dependencies, you can check the official documentation for [resource manager](https://github.com/googleapis/java-resourcemanager). Also, here is the link where can check the client used to get projects, [project client](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-resourcemanager/latest/com/google/cloud/resourcemanager/v3/ProjectsClient.html)

**Workarounds:**

Alternatively you can use other libraries and cmds to get that information, it makes use of bigquery python client library to get the information you are looking for:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"
key_path = "my-service-account-key.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)

print(client.get_service_account_email())

projects = client.list_projects(max_results=10)

for project in list(projects):
    print(project.project_id)
    print(project.numeric_id)
```

**Note**: follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287267/how-can-i-get-the-file-service-account-json-for-google-translate-api) for guidance on how to get a service account json.

output

```
bq-service-account-project-number@bigquery-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com
project id: my-project-id
project number: 7788990000xxx
```

Another options outside bigquery resources to get info about projects. You can get that information you will have to open `google cloud shell` and perform the following command:

```
gcloud projects describe <my-project-id>
```

output:

```
createTime: '2015-10-20T10:12:09.452Z'
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
name: my-project-id
parent:
  id: '111222333xxx'
  type: folder
projectId: my-project-id
projectNumber: '777555000xxx'
```

Also, I'm leaving these links where you can get project related info:

- [Bigquery Libraries Documentation - Python Client](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client), where you can get info about the projects and service account mail related to an account. ( as displayed in the sample )
- [Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata), which also contains project id. ( not project number )
- [Querys](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata) (schema information)

Finally, If you are looking about why its difficult to get info from bigquery about projects I'm providing this link that discuss about [resource-hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/resource-hierarchy).

Comment: Hi Betjens, thanks for your detailed response, but I am particularly looking at JAVA API, I have searched for that and found one repo .
https://github.com/googleapis/java-resourcemanager 

Through that i was able to get the project details, but the methods are deprecated . That's the only issue, trying to find out the alternative for that

Comment: Hello saivasanth, I have updated my response.

Comment: Indeed, As you mention, java-resourcemanager its the only way at the moment. From bigquery client you will not be able to get that info.

Comment: Also, java-resourcemanager is still alive, its on v3 at the moment.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I had posted my answer which fitted to my use case, please go through it

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it in this way, here the methods are deprecated, finding out the alternatives for this like moving of this artifact to our own artifactory like that which is out of the context currently, but I got the info that I want through the java client.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-resourcemanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the dependency that I have added in my pom.xml file

```
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.ResourceManager;
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.ResourceManagerOptions;
import com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.Project;
String credentialsPath = "tmp/credentials.json";
ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManagerOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("my-project-id").
            setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsPath))).build().getService();
  

 Project project = resourceManager.get(projectId);
// You got the project object which contains the details you needed
```

You need two permissions to get the details of the project

1. projects.get
2. Enable [this](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager) API for your project

If these permissions are correct , you will get the details otherwise null object will be returned from the google side